# Excel Reader c# (E+15 Issue)

Tags: excel

I load my excel to gridview in c# Winform and I use [Excel.4.5](https://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/) for reading.My value in my excel row cell 7885266361743930.But it comes to my gridview like this => 7,88526636174393E+15 in normal what I waiting

is => 7885266361743930 like in my excel :)

This is my method to read the **excel** :

```
var stream = File.Open(openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory + openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

Comment: It's not clear what your question is; can you edit the question to actually ask the question you need help with?

Comment: Excel has a 15 digit 'floating point' accuracy. If you need to deal with larger numbers then store as text and deal with internal maths, returning the result as text if more than 15 significant digits are required.

Comment: I am sorry for non-info ,now my question is correct :) @Jeeped ımm maybe it is  realy not as string in my excel how can I look that ?.

Comment: You should test with **7885266361743935** not **7885266361743930** because a value in Excel stored as **7885266361743935** will change to a raw underlying value of  **7885266361743930** .

Comment: @Jeeped but this is important like IBAN in banks.I need to load with zero and print again with zero

Comment: @AlicanKablan - I don't think we are on the same wavelength. I am cautioning against relying on accuracy beyond 15 significant digits for stored numbers. See [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dz7bQ.png) for an example. If these numbers were used internally for maths they would not lose their accuracy.

Comment: @Jeeped I understand you I store my data in the column as text from now.Thanks for your help  :)